# AnyMsg equivalent in C++

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there any C++ alternative to rospy.AnyMsg? I need to forward a message in binary format so that I would like my node to subscribe to an unserialized version of the message, or something similar. The only solution I found so far is to create a custom adaptation as explained [here in point 3.3](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes), but this requires to customize the traits for every message type.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221869/anymsg-equivalent-in-c++/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-12-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-02**:
search the wiki for something called shapeshifter

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-12-02**:
I saw it but for any reason I do not remember I thought it was not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `relay` node in the topic_tools package uses ShapeShifter to forward messages without knowing their type: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/topic_tools/src/relay.cpp

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2